# Deleted Button after creating code. Brought it back, but code is not tied to it

Tags: c#, windows

I am using c# in Windows Visual Studio 2010.  I had to remove several controls on a form in order to insert two SplitContainers.  The event code for these controls was left intact.  After getting the two SplitContainers set up, I added the removed controls, one at a time.  I renamed them and set them up just as they were. When I checked the the "Event" I saw that none of the event items had been recognized.  Is there an easy way to re-associate the controls with the event code?

Thanks in advance,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is.  You'll see code like this in the `.Designer.cs` files if you created them with the designer and there's no reason you can't do this in your own code manually.

```
//Control.Event += AppropriateMethodName;
yourControl.Click += yourControl_Click;
```

If I interpreted your question incorrectly above, you may have meant that you removed them within the designer.  If that's the case, when you see the event in the properties window, you can click the drop-down menu and select from a list of existing methods that match the appropriate signature for the event.

Comment: Yes, I removed them from within the designer.  I went to the Event in the properties window and was able to pull-down and select the existing method! Your solution is just what I was hoping for! Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to redo it manually since the method no longer handles the event. what you could have done is that you shouldn't remove your controls just drag them left or right then drag them back to your splitcontainers controls.

what you can do is select the event from the events window in the properties but it is still manually or in the designer class but also still manually.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 0):

In the GUI you can click on your control, go to the Events list in the Properties window and choose the event handler from the drop-down menu next to the event you're interested in handling.  Visual Studio will list all of the methods with the appropriate signature to handle that event.  If you used the same control type and your event handler code is still there, then it should show up in that drop-down.